# How images are loaded into browsers?

Tags: html, css

I have a picture original size suppose 1024px X 768px. When I load it in website through css background property, I would accomplish this way:

1. `background: url('imgPath') no-repeat; width: 100px; height: 100px;`
2. `background: url('imgPath') no-repeat; width: 1024px; height: 768px;`

I've simple question on my mind: Does both styles load the page at same speed or first method loads the page at higher speed?

Comment: No, both have same image name(file path). The image size will be same. So it means that the image will have to be downloaded, no matter what the size is. Secondly you are using `width: ; height: ;` that will scale the image. So that will also take some time; in the browser to scale the image! But however I would really prefer not to worry about this. However if you are working for mobile site. Where 2G is the call. Then you should consider using these. You might need an image with the exact size as the screen will allow to save time. But no need on WEB(Desktop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both situations, the full image has to be downloaded by the client, so load times will be equal.

And if you really care: the first image will show up few microseconds later, because it needs to be rescaled first before presenting it to the user.

Depending if you use a server-side scripting technology, you could rescale and cache the rescaled image on the server. Example: the imageurl could look like `background.jpg?size=100x100`, where `background.jpg` actually redirects to a script page that generates or loads a previously generated image in the required size from cache.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 'imgPath' is the same for both images, both will load at the same time, because well... it should only load once. It seems your thinking that width and height may effect how an image loads, and that simply is not the case.

http://jsfiddle.net/ericjbasti/AKGB5/

Also you might be meaning to do this:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

If you want your height and width to scale the image.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be the same, the whole image is loaded in both cases because CSS works on the client-side. The only way to "speed up" the load time would be to do some server-side reduction of the image.

In this case I'd say you're better off using a thumbnail, otherwise you'd be wasting valuable server resources.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it will be the same speed. You could always try media queries like this:

```
   @media all and (min-width: 601px) {
     html {
     background: url('imgPath') no-repeat; width: 1024px; height: 768px;
     }

   }

   @media all and (max-width: 600px) {
     html {
     background: url('imgPath') no-repeat; width: 100px; height: 100px;
     }
   }
```

Here's a really nice article about it: http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/